# MinGw 4.7.0 doesnt compile code with #include <boost/thread>

Tags: c++, boost, mingw, boost-thread

MinGw 4.7.0 Boost 1.47
code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
std::cout<<"In main"<<std::endl;
}
```

Compiler string:

```
g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions  -g    -IC:\soft\ides_comp\mingw\include\boost_1_47_0  -c      D:\work\cpp_cb\mt1\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
```

It doesnt compile and i have same error whatever compiler options i tried.

Warning:
`In file included from C:\soft\ides_comp\mingw\include\boost_1_47_0/boost/thread/win32/thread_data.hpp:12:0,
                 from C:\soft\ides_comp\mingw\include\boost_1_47_0/boost/thread/thread.hpp:15,
                 from C:\soft\ides_comp\mingw\include\boost_1_47_0/boost/thread.hpp:13,
                 from D:\work\cpp_cb\mt1\main.cpp:2:
C:\soft\ides_comp\mingw\include\boost_1_47_0/boost/thread/win32/thread_heap_alloc.hpp:59:40: warning: inline function 'void* boost::detail::allocate_raw_heap_memory(unsigned int)' declared as  dllimport: attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
C:\soft\ides_comp\mingw\include\boost_1_47_0/boost/thread/win32/thread_heap_alloc.hpp:69:39: warning: inline function 'void boost::detail::free_raw_heap_memory(void*)' declared as  dllimport: attribute ignored [-Wattributes]`

Error:
`In file included from C:\soft\ides_comp\mingw\include\boost_1_47_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:30:0,
                 from C:\soft\ides_comp\mingw\include\boost_1_47_0/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17,
                 from C:\soft\ides_comp\mingw\include\boost_1_47_0/boost/date_time/time_clock.hpp:17,
                 from C:\soft\ides_comp\mingw\include\boost_1_47_0/boost/thread/thread_time.hpp:9,
                 from C:\soft\ides_comp\mingw\include\boost_1_47_0/boost/thread/win32/thread_data.hpp:10,
                 from C:\soft\ides_comp\mingw\include\boost_1_47_0/boost/thread/thread.hpp:15,
                 from C:\soft\ides_comp\mingw\include\boost_1_47_0/boost/thread.hpp:13,
                 from D:\work\cpp_cb\mt1\main.cpp:2:`

`C:\soft\ides_comp\mingw\include\boost_1_47_0/boost/checked_delete.hpp: In instantiation of 'void boost::checked_delete(T*) [with T = boost::error_info<boost::tag_original_exception_type, const std::type_info*>]':`

`C:\soft\ides_comp\mingw\include\boost_1_47_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:95:13:   required from 'boost::detail::shared_count::shared_count(Y*) [with Y = boost::error_info<boost::tag_original_exception_type, const std::type_info*>]'
C:\soft\ides_comp\mingw\include\boost_1_47_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:183:50:   required from 'boost::shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(Y*) [with Y = boost::error_info<boost::tag_original_exception_type, const std::type_info*>; T = boost::error_info<boost::tag_original_exception_type, const std::type_info*>]'
C:\soft\ides_comp\mingw\include\boost_1_47_0/boost/exception/info.hpp:171:69:   required from 'const E& boost::exception_detail::set_info(const E&, const boost::error_info<Tag, T>&) [with E = boost::unknown_exception; Tag = boost::tag_original_exception_type; T = const std::type_info*]'
C:\soft\ides_comp\mingw\include\boost_1_47_0/boost/exception/info.hpp:192:46:   required from 'typename boost::enable_if<boost::exception_detail::derives_boost_exception<E>, const E&>::type boost::operator<<(const E&, const boost::error_info<Tag, T>&) [with E = boost::unknown_exception; Tag = boost::tag_original_exception_type; T = const std::type_info*; typename boost::enable_if<boost::exception_detail::derives_boost_exception<E>, const E&>::type = const boost::unknown_exception&]'
C:\soft\ides_comp\mingw\include\boost_1_47_0/boost/exception/detail/exception_ptr.hpp:182:13:   required from 'void boost::unknown_exception::add_original_type(const E&) [with E = std::exception]'
C:\soft\ides_comp\mingw\include\boost_1_47_0/boost/exception/detail/exception_ptr.hpp:161:32:   required from here`

Warning 2:
`C:\soft\ides_comp\mingw\include\boost_1_47_0/boost/checked_delete.hpp:34:5: warning: deleting object of polymorphic class type 'boost::error_info<boost::tag_original_exception_type, const std::type_info*>' which has non-virtual destructor might cause undefined behaviour [-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor]`

What can it be? Thanks

Comment: What is MinGW 4.7.0? Do you mean MinGW GCC 4.7?

Comment: I'm guessing from here: `http://code.google.com/p/mingw-builds/`. Try the 4.6.2 and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compiled the thread library for using Win32 threads, you might need

```
-DBOOST_USE_WINDOWS_H
```

in your compiler flags. While I don't think that's the issue (I get a different set of errors for not using it), you might give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in later boost versions. Check here:

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6165

Update boost/config/stdlib/libstdcpp3.hpp:

```
#if defined(_GLIBCXX_HAVE_GTHR_DEFAULT) \
    || defined(_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS) \
    || defined(_GLIBCXX__PTHREADS) \
    || defined(WIN32)
```

Added _GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS and/or WIN32 (from the link above, see patch).

WIN32 seems a bit brute force, but doesn't work without (at least not for me. I am using an older boost version 1.42).

Answer (score 0):

This answer maybe not very straight, but:
I do use g++ 4.7.0 20111209 and it has support for threads.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void foo()
{
    cout << "Hello from thread\n";
}

int main()
{
    thread th1(foo);
    th1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

During compilation use -std=c++11 option to use the latest standard which supports threads

PS:
boost 1.48 compiled on my pc with mingw 4.7.0 gives an error (when trying to use boost::thread):
Threading support unavailable: it has been explicitly disabled with BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS
So I guess it was disabled by default with g++ 4.7.0 (with g++ 4.6.2 it was not).